# Python C-API module exit handler - an atexit equivalent?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm using Python ver 2.6.4

There is a function I have to call from a C library when my extension module exits/is unloaded. What would be the equivalent of atexit for a C extension module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Py_AtExit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sys.html#c.Py_AtExit) function can be used to register up to 32 cleanup functions.